# Dynamic SQL statement return value using the current target connection

Tags: sql-server, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm currently creating my first real life project in Pervasive. The task is to map a certain XML structure containing orders (as in shops and products) to 3 tables I created myself. These tables rest inside a MS-SQL-Server instance.

All of the tables have a unique key called "id", an automatically incremented column. I've dropped this column from all mappings so that Pervasive will not try to fill it itself.

For certain calculations, for a split key in one of the tables and for references to the created records in other tables, I will need the id that the database has just created. For that, I have googled the answer. I can use "select @@identity;" as a statement, and this returns the id that has most recently been created for the current connection. This means that in Pervasive, I will have to execute this statement using the already existing target connection object.

But how to do that? I am quite sure that I will need a JDImport or DJExport object, but how to get one associated with the current connection that Pervasive inserts the records by?

Or is there any other way to handle this auto increment when I need to reference the id in other tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is anyone looking this post up and wonders about the answer, it's "You can't". Pervasive does not allow access to their very own connection object, the one they use to query the database. Without access to it, you cannot guaranteed fetch the right id. The solution for us was this: We used a stored procedure which we called in the Before-Transformation event that created the header record and returned the id and an optional error message as a table. We executed it and it returns the id we then save and use throughout our mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how things work in Pervasive, but you may run into issues with @@identity,. Scope_identity() would probably be safer but may still not work in Pervasive.

Hopefully your tables have a natural key in addition to the generated id, in which case you can select your id based on the natural key. This will avoid any issues you may have with disparate sessions and scope.

Comment: Usually, our tables do not have a key that we fill manually, we leave this to the RDBMS. Still, the suggestion about scope_identity() is valid, and I took a look. We will not have clashing scopes that insert rows in triggers. So both statements should provide the same IDs.